# How to zoom out image out of the html container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html table in side a div tag which in body of html page. I have an image in one of the td element of table. My requirement is to zoom out the image (as in most of the e commerce sites) when I mouse over the image over td element.

I found the code and able to do it. But the problem is that it restricts to `<td><div>` container only and doesn't zoom out over other sections.

This is my `<td>` tag -

```
<td colspan="4"><img class ="blog" src="shirt.jpg" alt="Item" border='3' height='390' width='638'/></td>
```

This is the CSS -

```
.blog:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    height:475px;
    width: 350px;
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKX3J.jpg).

Comment: Try setting overflow:auto for the td element outside the image.

Comment: Tried. That didnt help:(. `.tdflow{
 overflow: auto;
}` `<td colspan="4" class="tdflow"><img class ="blog" src="`

Comment: What behaviour do you expect? Should the image go over the boundaries or not? Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3v4F/1/

Comment: thats exactly what I need Nix. But smhow unable to get it worked. tried with z index as well. `.blog:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    height:475px;
    width: 350px;
 z-index:999;
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
 
}
`

Comment: Have added the screenshot for more details. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

add `postion:absolute;` to `.blog:hover`

Make sure that the parent of the img has its position set or absolute so that the image does not show up on some unwanted portion of the page.

```
.blog:hover {
    postion:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:475px;
    width: 350px;
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: God knows what the problem is. It didnt help either:(. `.blog:hover {
 postion:absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:475px;
    width: 350px;
 z-index:999;
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
 overflow: auto;
 
}` Parent TD `.tdflow{
 overflow: auto;
 postion:relative;
}` TD Parent DIV `.contain div {
background-color:666677;
..
font: 10pt Arial,Helvetica;
overflow:auto


}
.mpd1{..;position:absolute}`

Comment: For some reason `overflow: auto` in div tag caused it. Remved it and replaced with `z-index:999;` and it worked:). Thank you for your help. Upvote !!

Comment: Its getting zoomed but not on the top i.e. not hiding another div elements. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw this fiddle out as an idea - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/vMh4R/).

I'm just not sure of the functionality that you want. Is the concept to hover over something and a bigger picture is visible?

CSS

```
.photo img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.holder {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}
.fixeddiv {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 200px;
    transform:scale(1);
}
.photo:hover  .fixeddiv {
    display: block;
    }
.photo:hover  .fixeddiv img {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: You got it right Tim. This is exactly what I need. Lemme try this.

Comment: If you want the image to zoom right over the top of the hovered image you do not need a holder.

Comment: Oh, OK. That's a good idea. I'm wondering if the use of js might give a little more functionality. I'll play with a fiddle.

Comment: And here's a fiddle using jquery that gives a bit more "ease of coding". http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/vMh4R/1/. You could use a single "magnifying" div, or you could have one popup next to the original image.